# Is there any APIs that allow you to call parts of the the Android SDK in c/c++?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, cross-platform

I wan't to build a crossplatform game for Android and iOS but I'm worried I wont be able to use the Android equivilent of Game Center and other stuff like that if I do so with something like Qt. Any way I can use these tools while still building the game in Qt?

Comment: OpenGL ES should be available on both platforms.  Qt, likely not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Android NDK.  See: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

> "The NDK is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app
>   using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of
>   apps, this can be helpful so you can reuse existing code libraries
>   written in these languages, but most apps do not need the Android
>   NDK."

Comment: I'm guessing the game center tools arent available in it...? I cant find em specified on google

Comment: AFAIK Game Center can only be used by iOS apps.  OpenFeint used to be the alternative on Android.  You'll have to search around for others, but I did find this one: http://swarmconnect.com/.